# Angular integration with VS 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, integration, angular7

This is one of the first interactions I have with angular.
Today I was asked about integrate Angular 7 with Visual Studio 2015. I have read some articles and I have seen some tutorials, but at this moment I only have found information about the integration of Angular 2 and 4 with VS 2015.

I also have read that VS 2017 already has the option to create this kind of projects, but I would like to know your opinions or experience about it.

Do know if this kind of integration is possible?

Do you have some kind of resources which could help me to made it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You can create a blank Web project and add JavaScript and HTML pages one by one and npm/yarn packages all using the VS IDE.  Therr are angular project templates to choose from too.

Specifically for VS2015 (I would recommend havingVs2017 installed) there was the grunt task watcher to help with the process of file on change watching, which helped me with Less stylesheet building to css without needing to learn the NG CLI NPM and node.

Mads K was huge in this space and has done several videos and written a lot of Vsix VS extensions. https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Web+Camps+TV/Modern-Web-Development-Tools-in-Visual-Studio-2015-with-Mads-Kristensen?term=Mads%20JavaScript%20visualbstudio&lang-en=true

If you go with VS enterprise you can get Browser Link working and get JavaScript debugging inside VS, as well as changing styles in the Browser and them being saved in the source file on your VS project, changing files in VS and having them refresh automatically in the browser without F5 ing

All that being said, JS development support in VS2017 was terrible and I had lots of troubles and have switched to debugging my NG app parts of my project using Vscode and using the NG CLI. Now Blazor and Vs2019 are out I'll give it another go.